# Symfony - adding record to db

Tags: database, forms, symfony, addition, crud

I wrote the code with a form that has the action of adding new data to database. It seems like everything is connected in the right way but 'Add' button doesn't respond and I don't get any errors so far.

> My Controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/theater-add", name="theater_add")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function theaterAddAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Theater Name', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('town', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Town', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('address', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Address', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('phone', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Phone', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('capacity', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Capacity', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('seats', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Seats', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Add', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right action-save']))
        ->getForm();


   $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();
        $name = $data['name'];
        $town = $data['town'];
        $address = $data['address'];
        $phone = $data['phone'];
        $capacity = $data['capacity'];
        $seats = $data['seats'];

        $this->container->get('theater')->addNewTheater($name, $town, $address, $phone, $capacity, $seats);
    }

    $build['form'] = $form->createView();
    return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/theater-add.html.twig', $build);
}
```

> Service

```
public function addNewTheater($name, $town, $address, $phone, $capacity, $seats)
{
    $newTheater = new Theater();
    $newTheater -> setName($name);
    $newTheater -> setTown($town);
    $newTheater -> setAddress($address);
    $newTheater -> setPhone($phone);
    $newTheater -> setCapacity($capacity);
    $newTheater -> setSeats($seats);

    $this->em->persist($newTheater);
    $this->em->flush();

    return $newTheater;
}
```

> my twig view

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('theater_add'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form_row(form.town) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form_row(form.address) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{ form_row(form.phone) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{ form_row(form.capacity) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form_row(form.seats) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I need some type of guidance because I can't find any of solution online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('theater_add'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
<form>
...
</form>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

`{{ form_start(form) }}` renders itself a form element ( in HTML template) and `{{ form_end(form) }}` renders a `</form>` closing tag, so basically you create the following HTML:

When you click the submit button the inside form is submitted which doesn't handle the `$request` object in your controller, so the `($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` never resolves to true and the following `if` (where the addition really happens) is never executed.

**To sum it up:** 
Just remove the  after form_start and  before form_end in your template.

Comment: I just saw that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple mistake..

I closed form tag twice, so Add button wasn't in the form..

```
</form>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```